# Inline assembly in C: Dynamic registers

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to inline some assembly code in my C code:

```
__asm { mov reg,val };
```

The problem: I want to define the register and value dynamically.
I know the 'val' can be a variable written in the C code, but I don't know how can I choose the register dynamically (i.e decide according to user input- register 'dh' or 'dl').

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an enum and switch in the C-code:

```
typedef enum
{
  R_AL,
  R_AH,
  R_AX,
  R_EAX,
...
} REGS;
...
REGS nReg;
...
switch (nReg)
{
    case R_AL: __asm { mov al,val } break;    
    case R_AH: __asm { mov ah,val } break;    
    case R_AX: __asm { mov ax,val } break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well ... That would require you to modify the code at run-time.

The `__asm { }` construct happens all at compile-time, so you can't affect its contents later.

Of course, [self-modifying code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code) is not exactly what modern operating systems are set up to do most easy, so you're going to have to jump through a few hoops (cache flushing, code being in non-writable segments, and so on).

Update: Of course you might be able to use slashmais's technique and `switch` between a set of pre-compiled versions, but I'd be scared about mixing code at that level (register clobbering comes to mind).